# AES GCM in swift 3

Tags: aes, gcm

I have an API which needs data encripted using AES/GCM/NoPadding. But in various posts in the internet I have read that apple has removed the GCM from the common crypto library. Could any one tell a way to encrypt the data using AES/GCM/NoPadding in swift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, GCM was never implemented in Apple's Common Crypto lib. If you're willing to get your hands dirty, LibSodium implements [AES-256-GCM](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aes-256-gcm.html), and there's a nice Swift 3 wrapper [here](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium), which should expose the necessary API.